# Flutter interaction with change in memory

Tags: flutter, memory, dart, setstate

I am trying to understand how a flutter Widget populated by a memory item behaves when the underlying memory item changes. My use case is that: by trigger of some event(using EventBus package), this underlying memory item **may or may not** change. If it does, then I would like to trigger a setState(), but not otherwise as I wouldn't want to unnecessarily call it. Kindly help me as to how I can achieve this.Currently the onclick changes the str but the Text widget doesn't change. My example - 
button click(acting as event trigger) changes underlying str item that populates the Text item. Thanks in advance.

```
  class _MainApp extends State<MainApp>{
  @override
  String str = "1";
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomText(),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
            print(CustomTextS.str);
            CustomTextS.setStr("f");
            print(CustomTextS.str);

          },)
          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomText extends StatefulWidget{
  CustomTextS createState() => CustomTextS();
}
class CustomTextS extends State<CustomText>{
  static String str = "1";

  static setStr(String a){
    str = a;
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text(str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I proceeded to use the fact that Strings and integers are passed by value. Thus one can use that fact to get effectively a copy which one can use to compare with the updated value to determine whether or not on event action a widget's properties have changed or not.